# React Native layout - text/icons appear "under" the image instead of below

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox

I have the following layout:

```
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <Swipe
          onSwipeRight={this.handleLikedJob}
          onSwipeLeft={this.handlePassedJob}
          keyProp="id"
          data={jobs}
          renderCard={this.renderCards}
          renderNoMoreCards={this.renderNoMoreCards}
          onCardClick={this.showCardInfo}
        />

        <View styles={styles.buttonArea}>
          <ActionButton
            buttonColor="rgba(231,76,60,1)"
          />
          <ActionButton
            buttonColor="rgba(231,76,60,1)"
          />
          <ActionButton
            buttonColor="rgba(231,76,60,1)"
          />
        </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
```

Unfortunately I'm not seeing any action buttons.

my styles:

```
    container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
  },
  imageView: {
    flex: 1,
    alignSelf: 'stretch',
    width: win.width * 0.97,
    height: win.height * 0.55,
    margin: 5,
    elevation: 5,
    shadowColor: '#202020',
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 0 },
    shadowRadius: 5,
  },
  buttonArea: {
    flex: 1,
  },
```

Swipe component view is from the prop sent to it (renderCards):

```
<View style={styles.imageView}>
        <ImageBackground
          source={{ uri: image }}
          style={{ width: '100%', height: '100%' }}
          imageStyle={{ borderRadius: 15 }}
        >
          <Text style={styles.itemTitle}>
            {job.title}
          </Text>

          <View style={styles.locationContainer}>

            <Icon type="material" name="location-on" color="white" />
            <Text style={styles.locationText}>
              &nbsp;
              {job.location}
              &nbsp;away
            </Text>

          </View>

        </ImageBackground>
      </View>
```

As far as I read, the buttonArea should appear below the Swipe component, not under it (which is not visible).

Any idea what I'm missing here?
My goal is just to show the buttonArea right below the Swipe component.
Swipe component has position absolute.

Comment: what is Swipe and how is it styled?

Comment: @tudor.gergely Added it